# document.ready(function(){ ... vs document.on('pagecreate', function(){

Tags: jquery-mobile

first of all I try to use proper "language" but I am not a programmer. That said...

I don't seem to be able to get jquery mobile to work properly.

When I try to change `document.ready(function() { ... })`

to

`document.on('pagecreate', function(){ ... })`

I do not get the same result; in fact I cannot even alert a simple message.

Furthermore I would like to use mousedown and mousedown events. The documentation of jquery mobile tells me that I could use vmousedown and vmouseup. Does not work either. Can someone enlighten me please. the jquery mobile.js is added lastly in my script structure of the dom.

Comment: Sounds like you're not actually loading jQuery Mobile -- double-check your network and error consoles.

Comment: "Use this event instead of the jQuery DOM ready() method to place all other jQuery events and functions, because it will work whether the page is loaded directly or through the AJAX call of another page." From [this source](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_pagecreate.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe relevant for others with a similar problem.
Linking to the jquery CDN instead of hosting the files myself solved my problem.